# Full transforms (affine + perspective) of complex shapes (circles, Bezier curves, controls) in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, perspectivecamera

Which Java library supports full range of transforms by 9x9 matrix, i.e. with last row also playing role?

`Swing` does not.

`Piccolo2D` does not.

Why are they so hating 2 more double values to process?

`JavaFX` supports perspective transform as an effect. Will this work correctly?

**UPDATE**

I am interested in vector graphics, so that complex shapes and GUI controls, including custom ones, can be easily transformed.

Comment: Would JAI PerspectiveTransform work for you?

Comment: I would like to transform arbitrary shapes, including circles, rectangles and Bezier curves. `JAI` looks for raster graphics, although this object can transform points and can be useful.

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify. I suppose you would need to roll your own then, right? I.e. set up your transformation matrix, then transform all points on each vector graphics object.

Comment: This can be challenging. For example, how to transform circle having radius and center point?

Comment: By making it an Ellipse. And yes, it's not exactly easy: http://www.davidsalomon.name/TaPadvertis/CurvedPersp.pdf

Comment: An alternative approach might be to create a raster buffer to represent your canvas (say, the floor of a room). Draw to that as normal, then perspectivetransform the resulting raster buffer.

Comment: I am not sure it will be ellipse. Far side should be narrower. So it should be some sort of irregular oval. But I may mistake of course.

Comment: http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Perspect/Perspect.htm#circle : "The square that surrounds the circle projects to a trapezoid. The circle itself projects to an ellipse which is tangent to all four sides of the trapezoid. Observe that the left and right endpoints of the axes of the ellipse where the ellipse is widest occur below the tangency points."

Comment: Ok, anyway I don't want to bother with this, I need ready solution.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why rasterizing and transforming that would not work for your needs?

Comment: A perspective transform of a circle will be an ellipse, unless the perspective transform maps some part of it to infinity.  Then it will be either a parabola (if tangent to the line at infinity) or a hyperbola.

Comment: Also, I suspect that the projective transform of a Bezier curve corresponds to some sort of NURBS curve.

Comment: @MarkusKoivisto it probably will, but first I want to look for a most cute solution.

Comment: Well a cute solution would involve a proper 3d engine capable of rendering curves.